# have only one datasource at firebase

Tags: ember.js, emberfire

I have a chat app, where I'm saving the groups and rooms in a Postgres database, and the messages are in Firebase.
I tried use emberfire, but once you add it, all the `this.store.find` are routed to Firebase database, and I can't do that.

I also tried added firebase script direct to the `chat-room-component.hbs` but of course, I cannot add javascript to handlebars template...

What can I do in this case?